# Selenium не реагирует на alert'ы

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Добрый день.

В веб-приложении при удалении позиции из списка вылезает confirm-окошко, требующее подтверждения действия. В коде автотеста обрабатывающий окошко участок выглядит следующим образом:

```
SetMethods.ClickElement(By.Id(General.StitchId(button_combine, childPosition))); //клик по кнопке удаления записи
WaitUntilSmth.WaitLittle.Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent()); //ждем окошко
Driver.browser.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

Два дня назад все тесты выполнялись без ошибок. Вчера на локальной машине тест начал падать на `ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent()` со следующей ошибкой:

```
The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:54623/session/4d597cd674e654ace5ac79c9a516cd61/alert_text timed out after 60 seconds.
System.Exception {OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException}
```

Stacktrace:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55632/session/b4277da23ac26cc6ce309e5a35c231a8/alert_text timed out after 60 seconds.
----> System.Net.WebException : Запрос был прерван: Время ожидания операции истекло.
в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTargetLocator.Alert()
в OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.ExpectedConditions.<AlertIsPresent>b__4c(IWebDriver driver)
в OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
в Expo2.Utility.General.AcceptAlert() в g:\Git\expo-2\Tests\NewSeleniumTests\Expo2\Utility\General.cs:строка 144
в Expo2.Tests.Catalogs.Support.DeleteChild(String Name, String subMenu, String subSubMenu, String elementText, Int32 childNumber, String[] button_combine) в g:\Git\expo-2\Tests\NewSeleniumTests\Expo2\Tests\Catalogs\Support.cs:строка 143
в Expo2.Tests.Catalogs.ActivitiesTest.DeleteChild(String elementText, Int32 childNumber) в g:\Git\expo-2\Tests\NewSeleniumTests\Expo2\Tests\Catalogs\ActivitiesTest.cs:строка 123
в Expo2.Tests.Catalogs.ActivitiesTest.FullTestActivities() в g:\Git\expo-2\Tests\NewSeleniumTests\Expo2\Tests\Catalogs\ActivitiesTest.cs:строка 181
--WebException
в System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
в OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
```

При этом при деплое на тестовый сервер все тесты по-прежнему выполняются без нареканий. На локальных машинах падают.

Изменения в тесты не вносились, разработчики ничего не правили.

- Браузер Chrome 52.0.2743.116
- Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1
- Тесты на C#
- chromedriver 2.23 (пробовались также версии 2.10 и 2.22)

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной ситуацией?

Спасибо!